# How can I return a value as an OUTPUT parameter?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to get the OUTPUT parameter to work, but for whatever reason, it's refusing to. I keep getting null as a result. If I do everything on the SQL side, it works fine. I tested it like this,

```
DECLARE @test INT
EXEC MyProc @number = 1, @id = @test
PRINT @test
```

which gave me the output exactly as I expected. I've looked over this code for an hour and it **looks** right. The likely cause is an `ID10T` error, but my brain just isn't seeing it.

```
public static int MyFunc(int id)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.MyProc", connection)
        {
            CommandTimeout = 120,
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        })
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", SqlDbType.Int);
            var param = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Debug.WriteLine(param.Value);

            return Convert.ToInt32(param.Value);
        }
    }
}

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc
(
  @number INT ,
  @id INT OUTPUT
)
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SET @id = (
                             SELECT Id
                             FROM   SomeTable 
                             WHERE SomeValue = @number
                           );
        RETURN;
    END;
```

Comment: Try command.executescalar() instead

Comment: @JoeC no luck there

Comment: You are passing the type rather than the value when adding the parameter.  FYI - Check out this article http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple typo ...

You are passing the value of the `SqlDbType.Int` that you are expecting instead of the parameter to MyFunc.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", SqlDbType.Int);
```

should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", id);
```

Comment: Oh. Dear. God. Like I said, it was an `ID10T` error!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param).Value = id
```

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", SqlDbType.Int)` this was the problem code. What you're doing is setting the value twice, once incorrectly and then overwriting it with the right answer.